# An alert when trying to change a value in a column in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have this dataset (the Titanic dataset):

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
url = 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/chrisalbon/simulated_datasets/master/titanic.csv'
df = pd.read_csv(url)
```

And I want to change for the column 'Sex' all the values 'male' with 'NaN'. This is the code:

```
df['Sex'] = df['Sex'].replace('male',np.nan)
df.head(3)

    Name                            PClass  Age     Sex     Survived    SexCode
0   Allen, Miss Elisabeth Walton    1st     29.0    female  1   1
1   Allison, Miss Helen Loraine     1st      2.0    female  0   1
2   Allison, Mr Hudson Joshua...    1st     30.0    NaN     0   0
```

And I want to roll back and change the NaN values to 'male'. But I tried this:

```
df['Sex'][df['Sex'].isnull()]='male'
df
```

But I receive a message: `A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame`

The change was made, but perhaps my logic is bad. Please, do you suggest a best way to code this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to deal with SettingWithCopyWarning in Pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20625582/how-to-deal-with-settingwithcopywarning-in-pandas)

Comment: I tried to follow the idea but to be honest the question of the link was a little confusing for me. Anyway thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The recommendation from `pandas` is to do the setting like below which gets rid of the warning.

```
df.loc[df['Sex'].isnull(),'Sex']='male'
df.head()
```